# Split CSV file after specified row Python

Tags: python, csv, split

I'm trying to split a CSV file that has 201 rows. The first 136 rows contains information that is different from the remaining 65 rows. Is there anyway I can split the CSV file after 136 rows?

The solutions I have found so far split the file evenly. I have looked into this as a possible solution as well: https://gist.github.com/jrivero/1085501

Comment: Read them in and then take two slices `rows[:136]` and `rows[136:]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) objects on your file object. *Slice* the first reader object up to the specified number of rows using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), and then read the rest of the rows using the second reader.

If the two parts are different by say delimiters, the two `csv.reader` objects can easily handle this:

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open('your_file_name.csv') as f:
    first_rows = list(islice(csv.reader(f), None, 136))
    last_rows = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')) # use a different delim or quote char
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Would the approach be the same if I was using pandas and its read csv function?

Comment: @wolverinejohn You can slice the file iterator directly and pass the slice to the csv read function of pandas.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the number of lines you need to skip you can use `csvreader.line_num` to know the line you're reading, you can find more info about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#reader-objects